# How to upload a folder on overleaf?

Tags: overleaf

[image]

I am able to upload a single image, multiple images at once, **but I am unable to upload a folder.**

How does one upload a folder on overleaf?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Remark, if you only need to read the folder as opposed to modifying it on overleaf, an option is to upload a zip file, then unzip it at the start of the TeX file using shell escape. Note that TeX file is compiled multiple times, handle that accordingly

Comment: Alternative includes using git https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Using_Git_and_GitHub although I can't get this to work myself

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember and checked.

You can create folders in Overleaf, but not upload them.

[image]

Comment: Maybe someone from Overleaf's staff might add some insight about the theme.

Comment: Hi, I am aware of this as well. I was particularly looking into uploading them. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Academic Once created a directory you can drag and drop multiple files into it (directly, instead of first uploading such files in the root and then moving them).